# Windows Powershell editor :save command produces "E471: argument required"

Tags: powershell, vi

In Windows 11, I've run `./git.exe config --edit --system`, made my change, and now I want to save the file.

If I type `:save`, I receive an error `E471: argument required`.

How do I save the file with the same file name?

Can't find the answer on Google.

Comment: I am not sure how you got `:save` but you can directly put it in the notepad++ edit and save it if that is what you are looking for `./git.exe config --edit --system core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"` For further reference, kindly check [git-config-documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

Comment: Git [defaults to vi](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) if it doesn't find a default editor from environment variables `VISUAL` or `EDITOR`. vi save as is `:w filename`.